# php artisan migrate не запускает миграцию, но ошибок тоже нет

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker

Зпускаю приложение Laravel через docker, все контейнеры работают, но при попытке запустить миграции, ничего не происходит, но ошибки тоже не появляюся.

Comment: не происходит прямо ничего не может. Может например происходить сразу выход обратно в командную строку. Либо все дело может зависнуть и ничего не делать. Оба эти варианта может и можно описать как "ничего не происходит", но по сути разные вещи. Список миграций вы можете посмотреть? Или в обратную сторону попробовать миграцию запустить, там что-то происходит?